# Antonym to word brother

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

Quite a few web resources claims that sister is an antonyms to word brother. I can agree with this in some way, but  how correctly it is.
So let say “relative” is synonymous for word brother.
In the same time “relative” is synonymous for word sister.
It seems like sister and brother in this sense are synonymous. 
Sure, if we take into account just sex (gender) it’s opposite things.
But it looks like depends on perspective relationship between two words mentioned above can be either synonymous or antonyms, which is becoming really confusing.

Appreciate if someone shed a light on it.

Comment: How is 'relative' a synonym for 'brother'? A brother is one type of relative.

Comment: There are all kinds of opposites.  Is the opposite of a square a circle or is the opposite or a two dimensional shape a line?  Pick a framework and work within it.  Pick a different framework and get a different result.

Comment: "Relative" is actually a [hypernym](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hypernym) to "brother"

Comment: Thesaurus.com is saying that relative is synonymous

Comment: Synonymy doesn't have a necessarily transitive relationship. Just because A is similar to B and B is similar to C that doesn't mean that A is similar to C.

Comment: If "relative" is a synonym for "brother" (which I don't entirely accept) then the antonym is "unrelated person". I can't think of a single word for a person like that, the nearest is "stranger" but that doesn't cover unrelated friends, neighbours and acquaintences.

Comment: A synonym is just something that is _close_ in meaning, usually not an exact replacement.

Comment: V.G., you need to give us at least one link to such a source so we can see it for ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A true antonym is a word opposite in *meaning*.

A brother and a sister are both relatives, or siblings, so I agree that in the context of discussing *relatives* they are not really *opposite in meaning* any more than *cousin* is the opposite of *uncle* - they are simply different relatives.

However, "brother and sister", like "male and female" are traditionally *binary choices* or *binary options*, meaning that if something is not one, then by default it must be the other. If you have a sibling it is either a brother or a sister (this is of course barring any modern view on the number of genders and I ask that if you feel strongly about that matter you do not allow it to cloud your view of how a question about English should be answered).

So, given a choice of two things, where it can only be one or the other, the two are technically *opposites* and therefore *antonyms*.

For example, "up" is obviously the opposite of "down". However, there are other directions such as *left* and *right*. They all have *contrary* meanings, but directionally there is an opposite relationship between *left and right*, and between *up and down*, reducing the 4 directions to two binary choices and two sets of anyonyms.

I would have to agree with the dictionary definition that "brother" and "sister" *are* antonyms when considering the (traditionally recognised) gender of siblings.

Comment: Let's hope neither the brother nor the sister has a sex-change. There will be a point in time when....

Comment: @edwinashworth That would only prove my point. If by a sex *change* you can go from being someone's brother to being their sister then the two are clearly opposite.

Comment: The changeover point is either neither or both, a third possible state. // But of course you're right in that the terms 'opposite' and 'antonym' are often used loosely, with the problem that people ask questions based on the misconception that they're well-defined.